# How to add up values from a php foreach block

Tags: php

My php script is getting data from an xml file. I am fetching a list of prices and echoing them in a foreach statement. The problem is I need to calculate the sum of prices outside the foreach. Here is what I've done so far. Converting to array then going array_sum is the only thing I can think of.

```
<?php

$data = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");

foreach ($data as $val) {

echo $val->price . "<br>";

$total[] = $val->price;

}

$sum = array_sum($total);

echo $sum;
```

So far, this is not returning the total. It simply returns 0, which is weird because when I vardump $total, it shows up as an array.

Comment: Try casting `$val->price;` to an int.

Comment: `it shows up as an array.` but if it is an empty array, than you will get 0

Comment: Nigel Ren casting the object to int works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using SimpleXML and you do

```
$total[] = $val->price;
```

this creates an array of SimpleXMLElements and not values.

A simple solution in this case is to cast the value, depending on the type of value either

```
$total[] = (int)$val->price;
```

or

```
$total[] = (float)$val->price;
```